# How to run java Google App Engine locally with app-gradle-plugin for yaml?

Tags: java, gradle, google-app-engine

I am using [Google App Engine gradle plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin/blob/24b99a66d5ebe2b51286dcc65bf3da379842738a/USER_GUIDE.md) with yaml file, but the plugin version for it has no task `appengineRun` or `appengineStart` like the appengine-web.xml [version](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin/blob/24b99a66d5ebe2b51286dcc65bf3da379842738a/USER_GUIDE.md#local-run).

Comment: Are you using App Engine Standard or Flexible? Which version of the runtime are you running?

Comment: I am using standard now, but it would be nice to know both if there is any difference running locally

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** `appengineRun` is only available for appengine-web.xml based projects. If you want to use `app.yaml`, you must provide your own server, for example Spring Boot with Jetty or Tomcat.

---

To run your application locally, you must provide your own server.

This [guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/using-gradle#testing_your_application_with_the_development_server) shows how to test your application using `app.yaml` alongside with the `app-gradle-plugin`, on section *Testing your application with the development server*:

> During the development phase, you can run and test your application at any time in the development server by invoking Gradle:
>
> ```
> gradle jettyRun
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can run Gradle without installing it by [using the Gradle wrapper](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/using-gradle#using_the_gradle_wrapper).

As said on this [comment on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/issues/946#issuecomment-832790123):

> If you want to use [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/config/appref) from your root directory, you must upgrade to Java 11. Learn more [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/building-app/writing-web-service#creating_the_appyaml_file). With the Java 11 runtime, you must provide your own server, for example Spring Boot with Jetty or Tomcat. The `appengine:run` goal does not work for `app.yaml` based projects because each server has a different start up command i.e. `spring-boot:run` for Spring Boot.